# Nonclosed Set that Contains all Limit-Points

Tags: analysis

Give an example of a set $A$ that is not closed but such that every point of $A$ is a limit-point.

I'm trying to think of an example of this in the set of reals (the real line) but I'm struggling with coming up with one. Is there an example of the real line?

Comment: Your title would more clearly express the problem given in the body of your Question if it were edited to "Nonclosed Set A that Contains Only Limit-Points of A".

Comment: Can you make explicit your definition of a limit point (for a set $A$)? Click "Edit" above, rather than placing the definition in a comment.

Comment: Useful notion: [Dense-in-itself set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense-in-itself)